# tf.abs() function producing complex output tensor from complex input tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following part of code -

```
...    
print(model.layers[1].output)
tf.math.abs(model.layers[1].output)
print('layer 2 output')
print(model.layers[1].output)
...
```

which produces the following output when run -

```
Tensor("generic_act_func_1/Complex:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 9), dtype=complex64)
layer 2 output
Tensor("generic_act_func_1/Complex:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 9), dtype=complex64)
```

I am not able to figure out why tf.abs() is not producing a float output tensor from the complex input tensor.
Thanks in advance for any help for understanding/correcting.

Comment: you're printing two times the output of `layers[1]`. give it a try with `print(tf.math.abs(model.layers[1].output))`

Comment: Well thanks, that really prints the float output.. does that mean tf.abs() function does not modify 'model.layers[1].output' internally? (which is what i want to do before passing the layer 1 output to layer 2)

Comment: exactly. `tf.abs()` doesn't modify the output, when you call it like you did. (I'm not 100% familiar with keras, but I guess you can add a `Lambda`-Layer which computes the absolut value) `model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.abs(x)))`  see: https://keras.io/layers/core/

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thanks a lot for the prompt help!